# How to encode a string in JavaScript for displaying in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043775/how-to-escape-html)

How can a string be converted to HTML in JavaScript?

e.g.

```
var unsafestring = "<oohlook&atme>";
var safestring = magic(unsafestring);
```

where `safestring` now equals `"&lt;ohhlook&amp;atme&gt;"`

I am looking for `magic(...)`.
I am not using JQuery for `magic`.

Comment: You could just append a `document.createTextNode(unsafestring);`

Comment: @Derek That makes unsafe string url safe but not html safe.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate: the suggested original is solving a much more specific question and requires a much more complex solution.

Comment: best answer is to use `Option` class's `innerHTML` Ref: [How to escape HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22706073/1417185)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

So then with `var unsafestring = "<oohlook&atme>";` you would use `htmlEntities(unsafestring);`

Comment: This is good for very specific symbols.

Comment: Quotation marks only need to be escaped for use in attributes.

Comment: @gdoron that's the point, only 5 characters need to be escaped (ampersand, less than, greater than, single quote, double quotes).

Comment: Nope.. you can safely use any quotes literally if you do not need to use the escaped string within an argument...

Comment: @Christophe, I believe this was just an example.

Comment: @gdoron example or not, it's still 5 characters to escape.

Comment: I think this solution is best. function toText (html) {
            var tmp = document.createElement("div");
            tmp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(html));
            return tmp.innerHTML;
}

Answer (score 40):

#### If you want to use a library rather than doing it yourself:

The most commonly used way is using jQuery for this purpose:

```
var safestring = $('<div>').text(unsafestring).html();
```

If you want to to encode all the HTML entities you will have to use a library or write it yourself.

You can use a more compact library than jQuery, like [*HTML Encoder and Decode*](http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode)

Comment: This requires jQuery which a) the question isn't tagged with and b) isn't needed.

Comment: @j08691, Yes, I noticed the missing tag, it still doesn't say it's not the best option, cuz he will need a library, and the most powerful js lib can do that as well.

Comment: Agree with @j08691, it works but it's just a heavy workaround. Why the upvotes?

Comment: @Christophe, though it was an old comment. People upvote when something helped them.

Answer (score 38):

Do not bother with encoding. Use a text node instead. Data in text node is guaranteed to be treated as text.

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Your&funky<text>here"))
```

Comment: +1 excellent point, although it's not clear from the question whether the OP just needs a text node or needs to combine the resulting string with others.

Comment: So great! An easy way around encoding :)

Comment: Additionally ```document.createTextNode("textHere").textContent``` will return the string value

Answer (score 16):

You need to escape `<` and `&`. Escaping `>` too doesn't hurt:

```
function magic(input) {
    input = input.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
    input = input.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
    input = input.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    return input;
}
```

Or you let the DOM engine do the dirty work for you (using jQuery because I'm lazy):

```
function magic(input) {
    return $('<span>').text(input).html();
}
```

What this does is creating a dummy element, assigning your string as its *textContent* (i.e. no HTML-specific characters have side effects since it's just text) and then you retrieve the HTML content of that element - which is the text but with special characters converted to HTML entities in cases where it's necessary.

Comment: I love that second "magic" version with the jQuery "hack." LOVE. IT. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if there is there any performance difference between the two? Is the jquery one slower?

Answer (score -5):

The only character that needs escaping is `<`. (`>` is meaningless outside of a tag).

Therefore, your "magic" code is:

```
safestring = unsafestring.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
```

Comment: Wrong: you still need to escape `&`.

Comment: I guess I'm used to allowing users to use character entities, since they're harmless.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was asking. "How can a string be converted to HTML in JavaScript?" Not, "How can THIS string be converted to HTML in JavaScript?" He wants a general solution.

Comment: I don't consider allowing input to result in invalid markup to be harmless.