# javascript vaiable and arabic language issue

Tags: arabic

When I hard code something like `<h1>Some arabic word</h1>` It displays correct words.

but when I update same `<h1>` By `JQuery` question marks are displayed. Remember my Arabic is stored in a JavaScript variable.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

**CODE:**

```
var arabic_dealer = "أنا";
$("#DealerDiv").html(arabic_dealer);
```

Comment: Read this: [Creating HTML Pages in Arabic, Hebrew and Other Right-to-left Scripts](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding  tag:

```
var arabic_dealer = "أنا";
$("#DealerDiv").html("<h1>" + arabic_dealer + "</h1>");
```

Comment: same issue, still. Secondly I dont want "<h1>" at all

Comment: Can you display the working hardcoded code as you mentioned then? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need proper encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

… or use the HTML5 shorthand:

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

Here's a encoding function for HTML Entities ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14130005/2493918)):

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Consider reading about JavaScript's encoding functions via Google Search.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your source (.js file or .html that you embed your script in) is properly encoded AND properly tagged with either header/meta for .html or `encoding` in `<script>` tag where you call .js file.

Also encoding all symbols above codepoint 127 as escapes can help you evade this issue completely. Some tools (like Google Closure Compiler) can do this for you automatically either as their direct purpose or side-effect.

```
var arabic_dealer = "\u0623\u0646\u0627";
$("#DealerDiv").html(arabic_dealer);
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Can you please show me an example?