# Modify htmlEntities popular javascript function to preserve "<br>" substrings

Tags: javascript, string, function, replace, substring

My question is based on the great answer from this [SO question How to encode a string in JavaScript for displaying in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129953/how-to-encode-a-string-in-javascript-for-displaying-in-html)

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

I need the same but should keep each `"<br>"` substring in the string. Looking for the best way to modify the function `htmlEntities` then.

Thank you.

Comment: why does this need modification?

Comment: It will replace "<br>" occurencees with "&lt;br&gt;" but I should keep all "<br>" in the string.

Comment: Just add `.replace(/&lt;br&gt;/g, "<br>")` on the end ?

Comment: oh, you mean you wish to not replace `<`, `>` if "br" is contained within.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you, I did the same but you were faster. Is it good enough or there are pitfalls? Seems like it is good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything smarter than my solution?

```
function htmlEntitiesModified(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace('&lt;br&gt;', '<br>');
}

//.replace('&lt;br&gt;', '<br>') was added to the end.
```

Please vote if this solution is elegant and good enough so I know. Thank you.

Comment: it's probably the least computationally intensive way

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
        return String(str)
               .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
               .replace(/<[^<br]/g, '&lt;') // negate `<br`
               .replace(/[^br+| \/>]>/g, '&gt;') // negate `br>` or `br />`
               .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
    }
```

```js
var unsafestring = "<br><oohlook&atme><br><br />string";
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/<[^<br]/g, '&lt;').replace(/[^br+| \/>]>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
document.body.innerText = htmlEntities(unsafestring);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very surprised no one answered this. You can just use the browser it self to do the escaping for you. No regex is better or safer than letting the browser do what it does best, handle HTML.

```
function escapeHTML(str){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    return p.innerHTML;
}
```

or a short alternative using the [Option()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) constructor

```
function escapeHTML(str){
    return new Option(str).innerHTML;
}
```