# Print Javascript Array Value Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-encode

So I have a javascript array and in the array I have this:

```
var quiz = [{
    "question": "What is the greatest common factor of 105 and 126?",
    "image": "",
    "choices": ["3", "7",
        "9", "21", "35"
    ],
    "correct": "21",
    "conceptlink": "https://www.khanacademy.org/math/in-sixth-grade-math/playing-numbers/highest-common-factor/v/greatest-common-divisor",
    "explanation": "In order to solve this question, you must factor each number into prime factors<h1>Height</h1>",
}];
```

Focus on the *explanation* subset of the array. I have an H1 element that I want to print but, instead, it is printed as part of a text instead of code. In other words, the text would read:

[image]

Instead of:
[image]

Here's the code that prints the explanation

```
 $('#explanation').html('<strong>Incorrect.</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
```

Any help from the js experts would be gladly appreciated!!

Comment: `htmlEncode()` seems to work correctly :)

Comment: Unfortunately. I tested it multiple times. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it. I'm not sure what your function htmlEncode() does, but if you don't use it, it should give you what you want. Here's a jsbin demonstrating it: http://jsbin.com/yeyuqoqabe/edit?html,output

If you want to know how to make the string HTML safe, here's a question that can help: [How to encode a string in JavaScript for displaying in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129953/how-to-encode-a-string-in-javascript-for-displaying-in-html)

Comment: Thanks. I thought htmlEncode was native to Jquery. I found the source code and edited the function!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to escape yout text.

```
var escaped = $("<div>").text(quiz[0]['explanation']).html();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ouu6x2ge/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need htmlEncode for that. I would suggest you try:

```
$('#explanation').html('<strong>Incorrect.</strong><span>').find('span').text(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']))
```