# Can I embed source files from GitHub on my web page other than Gists?

Tags: github, gist

#### Context

You can create a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) on GitHub and embed it on your web page: [embedding Gists](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/#embedding-gists).

This is an example of a randomly chosen Gist: [`tap.groovy`](https://gist.github.com/timyates/6126218).

#### Question

Is embedding also possible with other code files from GitHub, for example with this randomly chosen C# file [`ICommand.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ObjectModel/src/System/Windows/Input/ICommand.cs) which is not a Gist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could just `fetch` the file to embed on one's website.

```js
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/AutomationAcc/test1.ps1")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => document.getElementById('code').textContent = data)
```

```html
<pre id="code"></pre>
```

Answer (score 45):

You can try https://emgithub.com, which does exactly what you want.

To embed the example file `ICommand.cs` in your question, you can just add "em" before "github.com" in the address bar, then press Enter.

Then you can get a script tag like this:

```html
<script src="https://emgithub.com/embed-v2.js?target=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdotnet%2Fcorefx%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fsrc%2FSystem.ObjectModel%2Fsrc%2FSystem%2FWindows%2FInput%2FICommand.cs&style=default&type=code&showBorder=on&showLineNumbers=on&showFileMeta=on&showCopy=on"></script>
```

Note if you simply click `Run code snippet` in StackOverflow, the copying button at top right corner may not work. Running it outside SO would work fine.

Unlike other websites that do similar work, EmGithub.com is a static site hosted on Github Pages. Fetching target files and highlighting are done on your browser.

---

Disclosure: I'm the developer of it :)

Comment: That's the best option available as of 2024

Answer (score 14):

You can use https://gist-it.appspot.com/:

```html
<script src="http://gist-it.appspot.com/https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ObjectModel/src/System/Windows/Input/ICommand.cs"></script>
```

Comment: That looks to me like html.  Can you elaborate on how this would cause the Gist to be added to C# code?  I.e., once I copy that <script>, where do I paste it?

Comment: You would paste it into the iframe head or body.

Comment: Not anymore :( https://github.com/robertkrimen/gist-it/issues/20

Answer (score 5):

There's a standard for embedding content from one website in another via a URL, called [oEmbed](https://oembed.com/). Unfortunately, GitHub is not a oEmbed provider, i.e. it doesn't support oEmbed for its URLs.

I found a proxy service, [Oembed Proxy for GitHub](https://www.onlinetool.io/gitoembed/),
 which adds oEmbed support for GitHub's code URLs. You pass a GitHub URL as a parameter to the proxy's URL and a resulting URL can be be pasted in another website, assuming that website supports embedding oEmbed links.

Another obstacle is that not every website supports embedding oEmbed URLs. According to the proxy's documentation, [notion](https://www.notion.so/) is one website that supports them. I did some research and looks like it should be possible to add oEmbed support to e.g. [wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) or [jekyll](https://github.com/18F/jekyll-oembed).

This answer provides a very limited solution, due to small adoption of oEmbed. I thought it would be worth to spread the word nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible service is https://github.com/finom/github-embed. It seems to be unmainted by now for about 2 years, but [gist-it](https://github.com/robertkrimen/gist-it) seems to be unmaintained for even 6 years. I've tried neither, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gistYard](https://piyush-hack.github.io/gistYard/)

```
<iframe src="https://piyush-hack.github.io/gistYard/emd.html?lang=&from=0&to=&code=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/corefx/master/src/System.ObjectModel/src/System/Windows/Input/ICommand.cs&edit=true&dm=off" width="100%" height="330" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It provides features like **changing theme** , **cutting code** directly from raw , **edit mode** , **custom styling** and others.

Answer (score 0):

Ayan Mullick answer is the best, but here resolve little issue with jumpline taked from here
[How to escape HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043775/how-to-escape-html/22706073#22706073)

```html
fetch(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seyacat/reactive/master/test/basictest.html"
      )
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = new Option(data).innerHTML
            .replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
            .replace(/\s\s/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        });
```