# how to embed github file to a github pages blog post

Tags: github, jekyll, r-markdown

I am creating a blog using github pages and jekyll. I wonder if there is a way to embed code snippets from a github **file** (i.e., a file in a repo) in a blog post. I can find a solution on this page about embedding gists: https://gist.github.com/benbalter/5555251.

No direct solution for github files, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I embed source files from GitHub on my web page other than Gists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206157/can-i-embed-source-files-from-github-on-my-web-page-other-than-gists)

Answer (score 2):

Jekyll has a pretty nifty syntax-highlighting system (provides `_sass/sytax-highlighting.scss` is present and correct), so it would be possible to just copy the code over into a blogpost, using `s to wrap the code.

As per actually *embedding* from a Github repo, there is a pretty nifty project [here](https://github.com/robertkrimen/gist-it), if you want to check it out.