# how to prevent XSS in javascript string

Tags: javascript, php, xss

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<script>
var string = '<?= $_GET['var'] ?>';
</script>
```

To prevent XSS I'd want to make sure the single quotes are escaped. `addslashes` could do that but people could still break out of that by setting `$_GET['var']` to . eg.

```
<script>
var string = '</script><script>alert(/test/)</script>';
</script>
```

Maybe I should escape (with `\`) single quotes and `<`? Is that all I'd need to escape?

I suppose attacks like this are harder now that browsers often disable code from being ran that shows up in the GET string but idk I still think it's something that ought to be protected against .

Comment: Thumb rule: json_encode() for JavaScript, htmlspecialchars() for HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043775/how-to-escape-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043775/how-to-escape-html)

Answer (score 1):

by

```
<script>
var string = <?= json_encode($_GET['var']) ?>;
</script>
```

without the surrounding quotes.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` would still be needed for the `<` and `>` but I'm thinking that's the best answer. Well that and the fact that the surrounding string delimiters (single quote in this case) shouldn't be present since `json_encode` adds them.

Comment: @neubert, about `htmlspecialchars` for the html-tags. Just did a quick test on phpfiddle, and it seems that `json_encode()` takes care of that. Although it only escapes the backslash in the injected `</script>` tag, checking the DOM, the Browser seems fine with that. So I'd be more worried that htmlspecialchars may change the string and therefore its meaning.

Comment: `json_encode($_GET['var'], JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS)`
Submitted edit to the answer.

Comment: without `JSON_HEX_* ` the following attack is possible:
`<?php
$_GET['var'] = " '><a href=/test>click me<!--";
?>
<div onmouseover='x = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['var']) ?>'></div>`

Comment: @VasiliyZverev Thanks for pointing this out, again I've learned something I wasn't aware of, but I don't think this applies to the actual question asked.

Comment: @VasiliyZverev `onmouseover`'s value is JavaScript inside HTML, so for that you probably want to use `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($_GET['var']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var string = <?= json_encode($_GET['var'], JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS) ?>;
</script>
```

Please note that no surrounding quotes needed. `json_encode()` produces quoted string `"bla-bla-bla"`.
Parameters `JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS` convert `"`, `<`, `>`, `&`, `'` to hex like `\u003C`. This helps against XSS when JS is inline:

```
<?php
    $_GET['var'] = " '><a href=/test>click me<!--";
?>
<div onmouseover='x = <?= json_encode($_GET['var'], JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS) ?>'></div>
```