# Do I need to "clean up" after HTML Escape a Javascript string?

Tags: javascript, html-encode

I have a Javascript application where I need to escape characters like "<" and ">" in a string.

This looks like an ideal solution:

> [How to escape HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043775/how-to-escape-html)
>
> ```
> function escapeHTML(str){
>     var p = document.createElement("p");
>     p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
>     return p.innerHTML;
> }
> ```
>
> or a short alternative using the
>   [Option()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)
>   constructor
>
> ```
> function escapeHTML(str){
>     return new Option(str).innerHTML;
> }
> ```

Q: Does this actually add "p" (and the associated text) to my DOM?

Q: Do I need a "removeChild()" or any other "cleanup" if all I want to save is the escaped string?

Comment: " I have a Javascript application where I need to escape characters like "<" and ">" in a string." - why? Are you presenting them somewhere? At which case don't escape them ad-hoc and instead set the textContent of elements instead of their innerHTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A1: No, that would be if the function also called `document.body.appendChild(p);`

A2: No, as you can probably guess from A1. After the function returns, its local variables are discarded, the `p` becomes unreachable, and will eventually be garbage-collected.

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I wanted to confirm.  Thank you very much!